# What's more accurate than GPS in determining location on mobile

Tags: javascript, java, android, cordova

I have a company where I want to **show every detail** like offices, ladders and WC's on a map on a mobile app to be displayed to **visitors**.

I want also to track the visitors inside the company or "Mall" through their mobiles ... **counting them** a day for example , and making a **small social network**  between them.

**GPS unfortunately isn't accurate enough** to be used here. can you suggest a better localization method ?

Comment: GPS should be accurate up to 1 meter.

Comment: when I use google maps my location isn't accurate enough it's almost 10 meters away ! where can I find the conditions to be accurate 1 meter -inside a building- !

Comment: This is exactly why iBeacons and other low power bluetooth technologies have been invented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bluetooth beacons are designed for this kind of thing but depend on you getting users to download the app and turn on Bluetooth. Look into Apple's [iBeacon](https://developer.apple.com/ibeacon/) standard and Google's [Eddystone](https://developers.google.com/beacons/). Both can be used on Android and iOS.

Comment: I have explored Beacon. it's a thing which says look I am here up to 70 meter ! can you tell me please how It will be used in determining user locations in the real time ?

Comment: Your app will get a beacon id and distance from a beacon. If you have multiple beacons and know where they are in physical space, you should be able to triangulate the user's location as long as you can detect at least 3 of them.